# $ P$ $ \Rightarrow$ ($Q$ or $R$) is not equivalent to $P, \neg Q\Rightarrow R$?

Tags: logic

Suppose we wish to prove this implication  $ P$ $ \Rightarrow$ ($Q$ or $R$):

So,we suppose that $P$ is true and then we try to show that $\neg Q \Rightarrow R$ ;to do that we suppose that $ \neg Q $ is true then we prove $R$.

Summing-up,we need to assume that $P$ and $\neg Q$ are both true ,then if we prove $R$ we're done.i.e we only need to prove that:

$$\begin {cases}  
P \\
              &&    \ \Rightarrow R \\  
\neg Q\\ 
\end {cases}$$

but there no equivalence betwen the two statments ,what am I missing here ?

Comment: They are equivalent, why do you say they aren't? And even if they weren't, why would that be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no warrant to suppose $P$ must be true, and/or that $\lnot Q$ is true:

$$P\rightarrow (Q\lor R) \equiv \lnot P \lor(Q \lor R) \equiv \lnot P \lor Q \lor R$$

So, the given proposition is true exactly when one or more of the following hold: either $P$ is false, or $Q$ is true, or $R$ is true.

Comment: Yes, if you have $P \land \lnot Q$,  then $R$ must hold (for the proposition to hold). But that isn't an equivalence with the original claim, it is an inference, given the claim and the premise $P \land \lnot Q$.

Comment: $P \rightarrow (Q \lor R)$. For example, $(P \land \lnot R) \rightarrow Q$ would also follow from the claim, but is not equivalent to the claim.

Comment: There is no equivalence; you have posted an an inference, that *follows from the claim.*   Equivalence requires a $\iff$ relationship between the statements. What you are proposing as an equivalence is obtained by a $\Rightarrow$ relationship.

Comment: An inference from $A$ to $B$ is in the form of an implication, denoted $A\Rightarrow B$. An equivalence between two statements means each statement is implied by the other: $(A\Rightarrow B)\land (B\Rightarrow A) \equiv A\Leftrightarrow B$.

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. You can prove $(P\land \lnot Q) \rightarrow R$, given $P \rightarrow (Q \lor R)$.  However, we cannot prove $P \rightarrow (Q \lor R) from what you propose. Hence no equivalence.exists.

Comment: You're welcome!